# how to init firebase storage image in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage

I am using the FirebaseStorage

I have already implemented uploading image files to storage.

Uploading image file is profile picture, but whenever I change profile picture, I do not want to have existing image file, so I want to reset every time I upload it.

Because I think it is a waste of space.

how to init firebase storage?

simple my code :

```
tmpimagelist.forEach((f) {
        final StorageReference _ref =
            FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('${foldername}/${num++}.jpg');
        final StorageUploadTask uploadTask = _ref.putFile(f);
        StorageTaskSnapshot storageTaskSnapshot;
```

Answer (score 0):

You used unique path every time which create unique child for the database.
So instead, use static path.

e.g -> profile.jpg

```
FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('profile.jpg');
```

Comment: This is indeed the idiomatic approach: if you want to store a single profile image per user, store that image under the user's UID.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen , yes you are right that's another way also.